# Populate one form with data from another in Java (Netbeans)

Tags: java, forms, user-interface, netbeans

How might I pull the data from one form in order to edit it in another? For example, I want to edit the data in this window:

[image: Customer details window]

In this separate window (currently I don't know to pull the data from the details window and populate the edit window when I click 'Edit':

[image]

Any help would be fantastic!! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the data in a [POJO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object) for easier management, when required, pass a reference of the [POJO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object) to the other form via it's constructor of setter methods.

Take the values from the [POJO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object) and populate the fields of the form

If the use selects <kbd>Done</kbd>, then take the values from the form and apply them to the [POJO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object), otherwise, do nothing, as the object won't need to change...